# How to switch Keyspace in Cassandra using CQL?

Tags: database, cassandra, cql, cassandra-2.0, cql3

I used `USE billKeyspace;` to enter a keyspace and start using it. Now I want to exit this keyspace and enter another keyspace. How to do that?

If I use `exit;` or `quit;` it exits out of cql session itself and then I have to connect again.

Comment: `use otherKeyspace;` ?

Comment: You are right, that did work actually. When I tried earlier I was not using case sensitive keyspace name so it was failing.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To switch keyspaces I didn't find any other way but to use `USE otherKeySpace;`.

Answer (score 9):

You can switch simply by "use" command.

```
cqlsh>    DESC KEYSPACEs;

system_distributed system_auth system system_traces

cqlsh> use system_distributed;
cqlsh:system_distributed>
cqlsh:system_distributed>
cqlsh:system_distributed> use system_auth;
cqlsh:system_auth>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it without use `USE` command, like this:

```
 select * from KeySpace1.tbl ;
 select * from KeySpace2.tbl ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use quotes around your keyspace name, especially if it contains other symbols than letters.

```
use "test-space";
```